# Wpautop stops working after get_the_excerpt

Tags: shortcode, excerpt, wp-autop

```
        function pre_process_shortcode($content){
            global $shortcode_tags, $shortcodes;

            // Backup current registered shortcodes and clear them all out
            $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;

        add_shortcode('bloglist','bloglist_func');

             // Do the shortcode (only the one above is registered)
            $content = do_shortcode($content);

            // Put the original shortcodes back
            $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;

            return $content;
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'pre_process_shortcode', 7);

        // Allow Shortcodes in Widgets
        add_filter('widget_text', 'pre_process_shortcode', 7);

    function bloglist_func ($atts,$content=null){   
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'number'        =>  2,
        ), $atts));
        ob_start();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     =>  'post',
            'showposts'     =>  $number,
            'status'        =>  'publish',
            'orderby'       =>  'date',
            'order'         =>  'DESC',
        );

        $latest = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($latest->have_posts()):?>
        <div class="bloglist">';
        <?php
            while($latest->have_posts()): $latest->the_post();?>

<div <?php post_class('post');?> id="post-<?php the_ID();?>">
    <div class="date" title="<?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>">              
        <span class="month"><?php the_time('F'); ?></span>
        <span class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span>
        <span class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
        <?php if($post_type=='post'):?>
        <div class="meta">
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" title="<?php printf(__('Posted by %s','wi') , get_the_author() ); ?>" rel="author" class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
            <span class="slash">/</span>
            <?php comments_popup_link( __('Leave a comment','wi'), __('1 comment','wi'), __('% comment','wi'), 'comment-link', __('Comments are closed','wi') ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php else: // post type == 'portfolio'?>
        <div class="categories">
            <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'category', '', '<span class="slash">/</span>', '' );?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; // endif post_type ?>
        <div class="excerpt">
            <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,120);?> &hellip;</p>
            <div><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="readmore"><?php _e('Read more &rarr;','wi');?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        endif;  // have posts
        wp_reset_query();
        $return = ob_get_clean();   
        return $return;
    }
```

Above is my shortcode. The problem is: when i add the line `get_the_excerpt` inside the code block, `wpautop` stops working after that. After removing `get_the_excerpt`, everything is back to normal.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean it "stops working"? You haven't tried to use `wpautop` after that line. Please elaborate.

Comment: As normal, WP automatically trigger function wpautop for post content. But if I use `get_the_excerpt` in the shortcode, all content after that shortcode is not effectless under wpautop. If i remove that shortcode, everything is back to normal. Note that, I triggered `do_shortcode` function in priority 7, before wpautop.

Comment: Please post all of you code-- the complete shortcode callback and your Loop.

Comment: Thanks for interesting. I've posted all my codes. Grateful if you help me to solve this.

Comment: I am not sure why you think you are "clearing" all the shortcodes, or why you think you need to add the shortcode in that roundabout way... can you explain in human terms what result you are looking for?

Comment: http://betterwp.net/17-protect-shortcodes-from-wpautop-and-the-likes/ Here's the reason.

Comment: I know why you might sometimes need to protect shortcode contents. What I don't know is why you think you need to in this case.

Comment: Because wpautop function will add some `<p>` tags after `<a>`, `<span>`,... and I want to protect the above formatting. (Don't want any unexpected element appears.)

Answer (score 0):

wpautop has got to be my least favorite part of working with WordPress. Just when everything else is working, it sticks its fingers into everything...

The problem has to do with filter priority, as you noted earlier. In the case of the excerpt, we're interested in the filter get_the_excerpt. I haven't been able to figure out what priority it has normally, and I also tried changing its priority. I succeeded, but it didn't affect my wpautop problem.

Instead of messing with filter priorities, I duplicated the functionality of get_the_excerpt in my shortcode. It would be better if I found a general solution, but luckily I don't have to use the excerpt in shortcodes very often.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
while ($latest->have_posts()): $latest->the_post();
    //$excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); // This doesn't work

    // Let's do it like the get_the_excerpt filter function in the core does
    // Once we get the excerpt by alternate means, everything else works again
    // See get_the_excerpt in /wp-includes/post-template.php
    $post = get_post();
    $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

    // Choose what to do based on whether it's empty or not
    if ($excerpt != '') echo $excerpt;
    else echo 'some fallback';
endwhile;
```